# Why doesn't std::ranges::contains try using member contains just like std::ranges::begin tries using member begin? Or does it?

Tags: c++, performance, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

[`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) can call the `.begin` member function if the argument has it. Also [`std::ranges::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/begin) seems to do the same.

However, at the page for [`std::ranges::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/contains) I see no mention of the word *member*, nor of `.contains`. Why is that?

I mean, if I was to write `std::ranges::contains(someRange, someVal)` I would really want it result in a call to member `contains`, if `someRange` happened to be a `std::map` and `someVal` a key in it.

I've also looked at `ranges::contains` from Range-v3, and it looks to me that too just makes a linear search through the range, with no special treatment for arguments supporting member `contains`.

Comment: `contains` was added in C++20.  ranges-v3 and its standard introduction all predate that.

Comment: that said other functions like `ranges::find` also don't use the containers `find` if it has it, so maybe it was just a missed optimization in the proposal.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yeah, I only mentioned `contains` but maybe `find` would have been a better choice in the first place, considering it is C++20, rather than C++23.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I mean, if I was to write `std::ranges::contains(someRange, someVal)` I would really want it result in a call to member `contains`, if `someRange` happened to be a `std::map` and `someVal` a key in it.

The problem is that these mean very different things. Given a `std::map<int, string> m`, `m.contains(42)` checks if *the key* `42` exists in the map, but `ranges::contains(m, 42)` would check if `42` exists *as a value* in the range - but the value type is `pair<int const, string>`, which isn't comparable to `int`, so this wouldn't even compile.

The two algorithms simply do different things, so you can't have `ranges::contains(m, v)` try to call `m.contains(v)`. That would be correct (though unnecessary) for `string` and `string_view`. It *could* be correct and an improvement for `set` but might be wrong (see below), but would be wrong for `map`.

The same is true for other algorithms where the general algorithm is based on the whole value type but some specific containers apply the algorithm to just the key (e.g. `find`, `count`, etc.).

Trying to check if `m.contains(v)` becomes a problem because these things in general tend to be very fragile in the presence of loose constraints (maybe the expression is valid because there's just no constraints on it, but there should be) or more flexible types (maybe some type just compares equal to everything, so the constraint is misleading - the canonical example here is using `std::any` when considering rules for constructibility).

And even if all the constraints are even legit and pass in a sensible way, that still doesn't mean that using the member algorithm is correct. For example:

```cpp
struct Point {
    int x, y;
    friend auto operator==(Point, Point) -> bool = default;
};
struct JustXs {
    auto operator()(Point a, Point b) const -> bool {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<Point, JustXs> points = {Point{1, 2}};
    bool a = points.contains(Point{1, 3});               // true
    bool b = std::ranges::contains(points, Point{1, 3}); // false
}
```

Comment: It's not really right for `set` either - you don't know what the set's comparator does and whether it is compatible with `==`.

Comment: But my point is why not having an overload valid only for types having `.contains` and calling that instead of the general-purpose algorithm? I'm precisely asking why can't `ranges::contains(m, 42)` have an overload that calls `m.contains(42)` enabled only for types of `m` that supports it? Passing, say, a `map<int, int>` and a `pair<int, int>` would fail to compile, and that would be ok.

Comment: @Enlico Fundamentally - `ranges::contains(m, 42)` and `m.contains(42)` can be different algorithms, and we have no way of knowing whether member contains is the same algorithm as non-member contains.

Answer (score 2):

`ranges::begin` is not an algorithm; it is a fundamental operation on a range (indeed, [part of the definition of the `std::ranges::range` concept is that `ranges::begin` works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range)). The entire purpose of `ranges::begin` is to interface with a range. Mechanically, `ranges::begin` is a customization point object for which an individual type that wants to be a range will provide a certain interface. That is the purpose of the object.

`ranges::contains` is an algorithm; it is a thing that can be done to a range, which has a specific meaning and purpose. Algorithms are not customizable, nor are they *intended to be*. If a particular range has a function that is named the same as an algorithm, then from the perspective of the algorithm, this is a *coincidence*. Algorithms are not a way to call a range's interface; they are a way to act on a range, to access or manipulate it through a range interface.

You should not confuse algorithms with customization points.

Comment: What does it mean that they are not intended to be customizable? What is the flaw in thinking that `contains` is an algorithm to check if an "item" is in a "collection", that it has a default behavior (linear scan of the collection), and that some "collections" can customize it 
 for better performance (map using a binary search)?

Comment: @Enlico: "*What does it mean that they are not intended to be customizable?*" It's not a difficult concept: the behavior of algorithms is not meant to be modified by the ranges on which they operate. Algorithms might have different implementations based on *range* properties (input-range vs. random-access), but they do not defer to individual functions on a range.

Comment: Maybe in the first comment I should have asked _**why** are they not intended to be customizable?_. Maybe I'm just making the mistake of thinking of `std::`/`ranges::contains` as a task/query/operation/utility that can be implemented with one or another algorithm, and for which it provides a default algorithm. Instead it _is_ an algorithm. So I guess the point is that `contains`, despite the general idea that its name conveys, is making a decision of an implementation detail on my behalf.